# How to populate the values of textfields in gridview in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an asp.net application with help of mvc4. i have 8 text fields.

```
    public class RegistrationModel

    {

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Programme Name Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Name of the Programme")]       
    public string ProgrammeName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Training Objective Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Objective of the Training")]  
    public string Objective { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Participants Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Participants/Target group")]
    public string Participant { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Faculty Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Faculty")]
    public string Faculty { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Duration Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Duration(in hrs)")]
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Max.no.of.Participants Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Maximum no of Participants")]
    public string MaximumParticipants { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Venue Missing")]
    [Display(Name = "Venue")]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    }
```

- And,this is the .cshtml code:
  I need to populate these values

  ```
      <ol>
      <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProgrammeName)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProgrammeName, new { maxlength = 50 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProgrammeName)
      </li>
      <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Objective)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Objective, new { maxlength = 500 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Objective)
      </li>
      <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Participant)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Participant, new { maxlength = 50 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Participant)
      </li>
      <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Faculty)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Faculty, new { maxlength = 30 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Faculty)
      </li>
     <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
      </li>
      <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Duration)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
      </li>
      <li>
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaximumParticipants)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaximumParticipants, new { maxlength = 5 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MaximumParticipants)
      </li>
      <li>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Venue)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Venue, new { maxlength = 20 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Venue)
      </li>
      </ol>
  ```

  I am in confusion that how to populate the values of text fields in a grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code or be more specific. By the way, to populate gridview from textfields you won't be able to you Bounded Items, so you will have to use Template Control for that.